# how to clear the 'The joined path is located outside of the base path component'?

Tags: django

I am try to add the static fills in python manage.py collectstatic but doesn't work

**settings.py**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'yuvaraj/static/')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', jobs.views.home, name='home'),
    path('blogs/', include('blogs.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: What is the expected output and what do you see now?

Comment: ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2.extensions'

Comment: Please update your question instead, thank you.